# bootstrap 4 - customize form-control-feedback with font icon

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm using boostrap 4 alpha 6 and I would like to customize input fields like form-control-success, form-control-warning, form-control-danger inserting font icons in custom new form-control-feedback css without using an svg image.

I find it in boostrap css

```css
.form-control-success {
    padding-right: 3rem;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center right 0.53125rem;
    background-size: 1.0625rem 1.0625rem;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath fill='%235cb85c' d='M2.3 6.73L.6 4.53c-.4-1.04.46-1.4 1.1-.8l1.1 1.4 3.4-3.8c.6-.63 1.6-.27 1.2.7l-4 4.6c-.43.5-.8.4-1.1.1z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="form-group has-success">
  <label class="form-control-label" for="inputSuccess1">Input with success</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-success" id="inputSuccess1">
  <div class="form-control-feedback">Success! You've done it.</div>
  <small class="form-text text-muted">Example help text that remains unchanged.</small>
</div>
```

it's possible to do it? 
Thank you

Comment: Can you overwrite the styles: `background-url: url() !important;`.